# Alternative to entering entity references in source code

Tags: html

[Google's HTML/CSS Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html) advises against using entity references:

> Do not use entity references.
>
> There is no need to use entity references like `&mdash;`, `&rdquo;`, or `&#x263a;`, assuming the same encoding (UTF-8) is used for files and editors as well as among teams.

```
<!-- Not recommended -->
The currency symbol for the Euro is &ldquo;&eur;&rdquo;.
<!-- Recommended -->
The currency symbol for the Euro is “€”.
```

I'm not sure I understand what it is that they are proposing. The only thing I can think of is that they are saying that you should be using your text editor's insert character command (e.g., in Atom, `Ctrl-Shift-U`, or in Emacs, `C-x 8`) to enter Unicode characters rather than typing in the literal entity references. Is that it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The only thing I can think of is that they are saying that you should be using your text editor's insert character command […] rather than typing in the literal entity references. Is that it?

Yes, that's precisely what they're saying.

You don't write `&#65;` to insert the letter `A`, after all! There's no more reason to write `&auml;` for `ä`, or `&hearts;` for `♥`, when those characters can be represented directly in the HTML file.